# Как при помощи Java Reflection получить поля полей?

Tags: java, api, рефлексия

У меня имеется такой класс, который содержит в себе другие классы в качестве полей:

```
public class SomeClass {

private String string;
private AnotherClassOne classOne;
private AnotherClassTwo classTwo;
private int i;

}
```

И вот мне нужно получить помощи Reflection все его поля и поля его полей, если это другой класс.

Comment: Получаете поле, получаете значение, начинаете процедуру с начала для значения поля

Comment: он возвращает тип Class и выдает левые поля, а кастить ругается

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку у меня нет классов `AnotherClassOne` и `AnotherClassTwo`, поставил вместо них `Integer` и `Boolean`:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String string;
    private Boolean classOne;
    private Integer classTwo;
    private int i;

}
```

Класс `SomeClass` у меня располагался в дефолтном пакете, потому объект `Class` для него проще получить по имени:

```
Class c = Class.forName("SomeClass");
```

также объект `Class` может быть получен из инстанса: `obj.getClass()`.

Далее достаточно использовать методы классов [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) и [Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html). На всякий случай отмечу, что класс `Field` придётся импортировать (`import java.lang.reflect.Field;`).

```
Field[] fs = c.getDeclaredFields(); // получили массив с объектами Field, соответствующие полям класса SomeClass
for(int i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) System.out.println(fs[i].getName()); // имя поля
for(int i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) System.out.println(fs[i].getType()); // класс поля
for(int i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) System.out.println(fs[i].getType().isPrimitive()); // примитивное поле или нет?
```

Для приведённого выше примера `SomeClass` вывод следующий:

**Имена полей**

> string
>
> classOne
>
> classTwo
>
> i

**Типы**

> class java.lang.String
>
> class java.lang.Boolean
>
> class java.lang.Integer
>
> int

**Является ли тип примитивным?**

> false
>
> false
>
> false
>
> true

На всякий случай отмечу, что результатом вызова `field.getType()` является инстанс класса `Class`, а не его строковая репрезентация, выводимая функцией `println()`. Это и позволяет к результату вызова применять проверку на примитивность типа методом `field.getType().isPrimitive()`.

Соответственно, если поле не является примитивным, то как раз и получаем его объект `Class` методом `getType()`. Далее для этого объекта `Class` описанной ранее процедурой можно получить его поля, типы полей, и для непримитивных типов опять повторить всю процедуру. В одном из комментариев этот рекурсивный алгоритм уже был описан.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте библиотеку Commons BeanUtils

```
String propValue = BeanUtil.getProperty(someClassObj, "classOne.someProp");
```